# Exibição de campo DateTime em View com horas, minutos, dia/mês/ano?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, view

Como manipular o `datetime` e mostrar na *view* no seguinte formato?

```
HH:MM dd/MM/aaaa
```

Comment: Você quer mostrar neste formato usando um input ou só exibir como texto?

Comment: Usando um input

Comment: Está utilizando Razor ?

Answer (score 1):

Sem você estiver usando `jQuery` você pode utilizar o plugin [DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).

Basta ler a documentação e aplicar aos campos que desejar esse formato.

Um exemplo seria fazer algo assim no `HTML`:

```
<input class="datetimepicker" type="text"/>
```

e assim no `javascript`:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

para que isso funcione você deve utilizar os arquivos `JS` e `CSS` do plugin em conjunto com o do `jQuery`.

Comment: nesse formato: ToString("HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy") soh me mostra a data e a Hora Zerada.

Comment: Você verificou se a data está com os valores de horas e minutos no banco de dados?

Answer (score 1):

No Controller

```
ViewData['MinhaDataMinhaVida'] = DateTime.Now;
```

Na View

```
<input type='text' value='<%=ViewData['MinhaDataMinhaVida'].ToString("HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy") %>'> </input>
```

Nao testei, mas creio que está correto.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Se for usando Razor, você pode usar [`@Html.TextBoxFor()` especificando um formato de data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh833695(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MinhaData, "hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Obs: a class "form-control" é do Bootstrap 3.